# Hover share link troubles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to position a link over all images on a site I'm working on and I'm having an issue with jQuery.mouseenter and then the user hovering over the link.

Here's my example: https://jsfiddle.net/13yxxww5/

My code:

```
jQuery('img').mouseenter(function(){ 
  jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeOut();
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/13yxxww5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add one thing, include link element like past of image see below code:

```
jQuery('img, #link1').mouseenter(function(){ 
  jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround it in a container and attach to that instead...

```
jQuery('#container').mouseenter(function(){ 
    jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('#hover').stop(true, false).fadeOut();
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/167k701p/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using pure CSS rather than jQuery if you're just trying to create a hover effect.

Here's the JSFiddle working with CSS rather than jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/69ysu5qd/

**HTML**

```
<div id="to-hover">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></img>
<div id="hover"><a id="link1">Link goes here</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hover {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
   opacity: 0; 
}

#to-hover:hover #hover{
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Take a look at this link for reference:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Hope this helps ;)